Best way to build a multilevel dict of dicts
I'm adding entries into a multi-level dict like this...
d = {}

level1 = "some level1 value"
level2 = "some level2 value"
level3 = "some level3 value"
data = "some data"

try:
    d[level1]
except:
    d[level1] = {}

try:
    d[level1][level2]
except:
    d[level1][level2] = {}

d[level1][level2][level3] = data

Is there a better way to build this dict?

Well, if 'level1' not in d: is better than try, in my opinion, but you can use defaultdict for this.  d = defaultdict(defaultdict)

A bare except is bad practice. Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting like except KeyError, or at least except Exception.

Does this answer your question? What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries? I haven't read the whole thing, just the first bit of the accepted answer, but it looks good.

Foes this help try/except/else/finally?

I think the link wjandrea posted does do what I want. Essentially I want to just use "d[level1][level2][level3] = data" and have all the intermediate structure created automatically. But the answer requires a bit of setup that is, in the end, more complex. Or I can just import yet another module as others have suggested.

A way to build a multi-level dict like your example:
The idea here is to make a dict constructor from a string
levels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
data = ['PLACEHOLDER']

temp = list()

# For loop must start with the inner levels
for index, level in enumerate(reversed(levels)):
    value = data if index == 0 else list(reversed(levels))[index-1]
    key = level
    temp.append(f'dict([({key},{value})])') if index == 0 else temp.append(f'dict([({key},{temp[index-1]})])')

# Transforms string into dict constructor
final_dict = eval(temp[-1])
final_dict

>>>{1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: ['PLACEHOLDER']}}}}}}
    

Since it constructs a dict from a string, keep in mind that the keys (represented by 'levels') must be integers
But if you still want to make a string key, you may insert the str in the levels list but you must define a same name var  outside:
# input:
level1 = 'level1'
key2 = 'level2'
random_name = 'level3'
levels = ['level1', 'key2', 'random_name']
data = ['PLACEHOLDER']
.
.
.
# output
{'level1': {'level2': {'level3': ['PLACEHOLDER']}}}

This solution is not as concise as yours, but can help if you have more sublevels

Dynamically constructing Python source code to eval it is sometimes a reasonable approach, but not here, and not  like this.
